# I have been fired once from a job I hated, but now I am struggling at a job I like. How do I keep this one, or move on if it doesn't work out?

Tags: professionalism, communication, termination

The first job was just an administrative job. I was even promoted, but hated the work so much I couldn’t hide it anymore. I was “asked to resign” which was better than a normal firing, so I didn’t end up in too bad a spot. Now I am in a tech support job which I like. I want to become a Developer, and I spend most of my time not at work coding in Flask an trying to build that skill set.

For the first 6 months of my current support desk job everything seemed fine, but now my employer has started to mention in passing some “concerns” about catching small details on my tickets and communicating professionally and accurately. I had been scrambling to close as many tickets as possible, and formed some bad habits.

my manager said there wasn't going to be any punishment, but he acknowledged that if I don’t improve that may be down the road.

Has anyone dug themselves out of a “concerns” hole before? if so how? I want to make this job work.

If it does come to a second firing, is my career basically over?

Comment: Why are you worring about something that can be changed? Your boss already told you you weren't going to be punished. And you said you liked the job. Use this time to learn what you are doing wrong and doing your absolute best to improve. What's holding you back?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds to me like you should sit down with your manager and really listen to what (s)he has to tell you. As for some genuine help in breaking your bad habits and becoming a better performer.

Express that you love the job and want to improve. A lot of companies have trouble retaining employees, so they will likely try to better train someone who wants to stay rather than hire a newbie and train them from scratch only to see them leave soon thereafter.

If I were you I would also keep it to myself that you want to make the jump from support to development. You were hired to do support. If you express a desire to develop it may be seen as a sign that you're getting ready to jump ship. Add this to the "concerns" and they may let you go.

Tackle these issues one at a time. First show that you're a great employee and improve your support performance, *then* express an interest in development.

I would also like to add a few details about jumping to development. I'm not sure where you live, or what the job market is like where you live, but in my experience unless you have some serious experience as a freelancer, or an education on the subject no company is going to take the risk of hiring you. Maybe take some night courses, or launch a business of your own? Build some experience as a dev if you really want to make the jump one day. Also, please realize that this might take a year or two, not just a few months.

Comment: thanks! I will take your advice to heart. I am working now on a portfolio project that is a full web app in flask and react, using lots pluralsight tutorials. In your experience, if an open source project is something you started and its strong enough, is it a strong compliment in a developer's resume? or just a nice to have? Also, any opinion on SQL certifiations?

Thanks again for your time

Comment: @yikes Having a strong open source project is very helpful in job search.  Just make sure you understand the difference between school and real-life projects.   Certifications can carry some wait if they are from well-respected authorities.  There's a huge difference in being certified by Oracle and by continuous education program at a local university.

Comment: The fact alone that you tell them you love and want to keep your job will help. If I was a manager having to get rid of one of two equally performing employees, I would always get rid of the one who is glad to leave, and not the one who wants to stay.

Answer (score 6):

Stop rushing, treat each ticket as just as important as the rest and do everything professionally and attend to the details.

You've had your warning, now you are under scrutiny, so take the managers advice to heart. This is normal enough and nothing to worry about too much. It's just a 'heads up'